# wagner.invoke doesn't recognize dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dependency-injection, mean-stack

### Background

I am making a small MEAN stack app, and I am using [`wagner-core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wagner-core) as a dependency injector in my test app.

Everything is going fine, except that I can't even launch the server ...

### Problem & Code

My test app starts with the `index.js`. This file bootstraps everything. Then I pass my `models.js` to wagner, and I terminate with the `api.js` file, so my server knows which routes to use.

**index.js**

```
"user strict";

let express = require("express");
let wagner = require("wagner-core");

require("./models", wagner);

let app = express();

app.use("/api/v1", require("./api")(wagner));

app.listen(8080);
console.log("Listening on port 8080");
```

**models.js**

```
"use strict";

let mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(wagner) {
    mongoose.connect("MY_CONN_STR_HERE");

    let  Mod = mongoose.model("Mod", require("./schemas/mod.js"), "mods");

    let models = {
        Mod
    };

    wagner.factory('Mod', function() {
        return Mod;
    });

    return models;
};
```

**api.js**

```
"use strict";

let express = require('express');

module.exports = function(wagner) {
  var api = express.Router();

  api.get('/Mod/', wagner.invoke( function(Mod) {
    return (req, res) => {
      res.json({"test": true});
    };
  }));

  return api;
};
```

The problem here is that for my `api.js` file, doens't recognize the `Mod` parameter that I am passing in the `wagner.invoke` function. For some reason, it is not connected:

**Error**

```
Error: No such dependency: Mod <- 
    at dfs (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server/node_modules/wagner-core/lib/topologicalSort.js:34:11)
```

### Question

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted the problem .... the problem was in `index.js`, where is `require("./models", wagner);` should be `require("./models")(wagner);`.

I hope it helps someone else facing the same error.